# how make a any time animation for iOS 6 xcode 4.6?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios6, uiviewanimation, xcode4.6

well how make a any time animation for UIViews, or UIImageViews in xcode, but mean while the user is in the app, the animatons show's any time, my animation is like this:

```
- (void)showAnimation
{


    [UIImageView beginAnimations:@"EFFECT_SHOW" context:nil];
    [UIImageView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIImageView setAnimationDuration:5.0f];

    self.imageAnimation.frame = CGRectMake(400, imageAnimation.frame.origin.y, imageAnimation.frame.size.width, imageAnimation.frame.size.height);
    self.imageAnimation2.frame = CGRectMake(-400, imageAnimation2.frame.origin.y, imageAnimation2.frame.size.width, imageAnimation2.frame.size.height);

    [UIImageView commitAnimations];
}
```

& when I call the metod, just i do [self showAnimation];, but in viewDidload, just show the animation a one time, how make anytime?, am I will need a "while" quiestion? or can I in another void?

thanks for the help & greetings from La Paz & Santa Cruz de la Sierra - BOLIVIA!!! rock on!!! n_n'

Comment: Not clear, what do you mean by "just show the animation a one time, how make anytime?" ? You have multiple imageviews and want to add animation to all?

Comment: o sorry, well I have 2 images, the animation shows the moving left->right  & right->left, but how can I show this animation Any time?

Comment: any time?? you want to do both the animations at the same time? or need to continue this throughout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just call the showAnimation method again after the animation is completed

```
 - (void) showAnimation
{
    //TODO: maybe reset you animation
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0f animations:^(){
            // define animation
            self.imageAnimation.frame = CGRectMake(400, imageAnimation.frame.origin.y, imageAnimation.frame.size.width, imageAnimation.frame.size.height);
            self.imageAnimation2.frame = CGRectMake(-400, imageAnimation2.frame.origin.y, imageAnimation2.frame.size.width, imageAnimation2.frame.size.height);
        }
        completion:^(BOOL finished){
            // after the animation is completed call showAnimation again
            [self showAnimation];
    }]; 
}
```

Comment: thanks but still not working, still shows no such infinite, I did call the method in viewdidload, in another IBAction from button show, but still not working, or am I wrong in something O_o?

Comment: add an NSLog(@"showAnimation") in the beginning of the method and tell me how often is the method called? did you reset your animation to the start state? what do you see? how often is the animation playing?

Comment: yes, continues printing "showAnimation" but the animation is not running, just one time, but later not showing anything :S

Comment: you just need to reset the animation to it initial position e.g. self.imageAnimation.frame = CGRectMake(0, imageAnimation.frame.origin.y, imageAnimation.frame.size.width, imageAnimation.frame.size.height);

Answer (score 2):

Use block animations which are a part of `UIView`. The [View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH6-SW1) has a great section on animations.

When calling the method

```
+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration delay:(NSTimeInterval)delay options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options animations:(void (^)(void))animations completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion
```

The "option" you probably want is `UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse`.

For example:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:5.0f delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat animations:^{
    self.imageAnimation.frame = CGRectMake(400, imageAnimation.frame.origin.y, imageAnimation.frame.size.width, imageAnimation.frame.size.height);
    self.imageAnimation2.frame = CGRectMake(-400, imageAnimation2.frame.origin.y, imageAnimation2.frame.size.width, imageAnimation2.frame.size.height);
} completion:nil];
```

Edit: Yeah.. it's my fault it doesn't repeat. According to the documentation....

> **UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse**
>
> Run the animation backwards and forwards. Must be combined with the **UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat** option.

I updated the code to include the `UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat` and it should work now.

Comment: wow that works, but just one time, how can I make this process does not end until you exit the application, I mean, the animation lasts since entering and exit the app completely, the animation should not ever stop, will I need create a new void? or where or how can I do that?

Comment: its like a infinite animation that i want

Comment: Yes, it was intended to be an infinite animation, I just messed it up a tad. I added in the appropriate documentation and fix.